# Combine different arity X-macros

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, x-macros

I am defining a lexer for a programming language. Part of this involves having a table of keywords and tokens:

```c
#define FOREACH_KEYWORD(V)                                                     \
  V(And, and)                                                                  \
  V(Else, else)                                                                \
  V(False, false)                                                              \
  V(If, if)                                                                    \
  V(Or, or)                                                                    \
  V(True, true)

#define FOREACH_TOKEN(V)                                                       \
  V(Plus)                                                                      \
  V(Minus)                                                                     \
  V(Times)                                                                     \
  V(Div)                                                                       \
  FOREACH_KEYWORD(V)
```

These macros are intended to be used like so:

```c
const char *kTokenTypeNames[] = {
#define STR(NAME) #NAME,
  FOREACH_TOKEN(STR)
#undef STR
};

// which would ideally expand to

const char *kTokenTypeNames[] = {
 "Plus", "Minus", "Times", "Div", "And", "Else", "False", "If", "Or", "True",
};
```

And the keywords should be included in the token list. The above pseudocode does not work because the two different `V` macro parameters have different arities. I would like any macro that has to deal with tokens to only need to take 1 parameter, and any macro that deals with keywords to need to take 2. I'd rather not make everything variadic. I feel like it should be possible to add some interstitial macros to make this combination possible, but I have as of yet not been clever enough to make this happen.

I suppose, in general: I would like to be able to take an X-macro of arity N and reduce it to some M where M is smaller than N.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear what the intended output is. In other words, assuming that some `V` existed that did exactly what you want, what exactly would that `V` do?

Comment: Could be anything -- I'll amend with a sample use

Comment: I think all you need is `#define STR(NAME, ...) #NAME,`

Comment: That doesn't address the `FOREACH_KEYWORD` inside `FOREACH_TOKEN`, does it?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to try. I don't know where I should be putting this call to `STR` inside of `FOREACH_TOKEN`.

Comment: Change the line `#define STR(NAME) #NAME,` to `#define STR(NAME, ...) #NAME,`

Comment: I would like any macro that has to deal with tokens to only need to take 1 parameter, and any macro that deals with keywords to need to take 2. I'd rather not make everything variadic.

Comment: I think we're talking about different things. I am not looking for a general-purpose parameter-counting machine. I just want to be able to splice together two "lists".

Comment: Please show the preprocessor-expanded output you want to see for the shown example. I.e. manually write what you want to be the result of what you are trying. That will help with guessing what you goal is. Please provide the desired output instead of only trying to explain it again.

Comment: Please update so that the problem caused by your intention to also use FOREACH_KEYWORD(V) is visible.

Comment: At one point you will get an answer to the question as asked, achieving the shown desired output. If at that point you notice that it is not how you wanted to use the two macros you will have to create a separate new question explaining that. When an answer exists which (technically, honestly, accidentally, intentionally, helpfully ... or not) answers the question as asked, it will not be appreciated if you change the question so that the answer does not match anymore. So, please demonstrate how you want to use both macros, in different cases (typical X-macros...) and with each desired output.

Comment: Make sure that the need for the second parameter is demonstrated. The question as asked now does not show that. Note that I nag about this, because the solution seems to obvious that I do not get the question, because I think "Naa, that can't be what OP wants....".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your specs I think this is what you're looking for.

```
#define AB_TO_A(A,B) (A)
#define EVAL(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define FOREACH_KEYWORD(V) \
  V(And, and)     \
  V(Else, else)   \
  V(False, false) \
  V(If, if)       \
  V(Or, or)       \
  V(True, true)

#define FOREACH_TOKEN(V) \
  V(Plus)   \
  V(Minus)  \
  V(Times)  \
  V(Div)    \
  EVAL(FOREACH_KEYWORD(V AB_TO_A))

const char *kTokenTypeNames[] = {
#define STR(NAME) #NAME,
  FOREACH_TOKEN(STR)
#undef STR
};
```

Coliru demo [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cb9f1c7d914dc58).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you think these two lists should be two instead of one, when one list includes the other. Either make one list or two separate ones.

If you make two separate lists and get rid of `FOREACH_KEYWORD(V)` in the `FOREACH_TOKEN` list, then you can simply make two separate macro calls:

```
const char *kTokenTypeNames[] = {
#define STR1(NAME) #NAME,
#define STR2(NAME, dummy) #NAME,
  FOREACH_TOKEN1(STR1)
  FOREACH_KEYWORD(STR2)
};
```